# Find solution minimum spanning tree (with conditions) when extending graph

Tags: math, logic, mathematical-optimization, discrete-mathematics

I have a logic question, therefore chose from two explanations:

**Mathematical:** 
I have a undirected weighted complete graph over 2-14 nodes. The nodes always come in pairs (startpoint to endpoint). For this I already have the minimum spanning tree, which considers that the pairs startpoint always comes before his endpoint. Now I want to add another pair of nodes.

**Real life explanation:**
I already have a optimal taxi route for 1-7 people. Each joins (startpoint) and leaves (endpoint) at different places. Now I want to find the optimal route when I add another person to the taxi. I have already the calculated subpaths from each point to each point in my database (therefore this is a weighted graph). All calculated paths are real value, not heuristics.

[image: problem illustration]

Now I try to find the most performant solution to solve this. My current idea:

1. Find the point nearest to the new startpoint. Add it a) before and b) after this point. Choose the faster one.
2. Find the point nearest to the new endpoint. Add it a) before and b) after this point. Choose the faster one.

Ignoring the case that the new endpoint comes before the new start point, this seams feasible.
I expect that the general direction of the taxi is one direction, this eliminates the following edge case.
[image: Edge case if taxi drives back and forth]

**Is there any case I'm missing in which this algorithm wouldn't calculate the optimal solution?**

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely many cases were this algorithm (which is a [First Fit](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#firstFit) construction heuristic) **won't find the optimal solution**. Given a reasonable sized dataset, in my experience, I would guess to get improvements of 10-20% by simply taking that result and adding metaheuristics (or other optimization algo's).

Explanation:

If you have multiple taxis with a limited person capacity, it has an inherit bin packing problem, which is NP-complete (which is proven to be suboptimally solved by all known construction heuristics in P).

But even if you have just 1 taxi, it is similar to TSP: if you have the optimal solution for 10 locations and add 1 location, it can create a snowball effect in the optimal solution to make the optimal solution look completely different. (sorry, no visual image of this yet)

And if you need to any additional constraints on top of that later on, you need to be aware of [these false assumptions](http://blog.athico.com/2013/08/false-assumptions-for-vehicle-routing.html).

Comment: Hello Geoffrey, thanks for the message. The problem size here is only one taxi. The TSP requires the salesman to come back, our scenario is one-way only. I have read your link, I still couldn't think of an suboptimal case yet. Can you give me one example where this algorithm wouldn't find the optimal solution.

Comment: It's hard to describe an example (I thought demonstrated one in my [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5D3hTjZlRc), but I probably don't). Anyway, here's the proof on wikipedia's TSP page: ["The requirement of returning to the starting city does not change the computational complexity of the problem, see Hamiltonian path problem."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Related_problems)

Comment: I have watched your video, thanks. I have a fixed 1 taxi and 1 request, therefore vehicle capacity can be ignored. Also the time frame can be ignored. I optimize only for one factor,  the travel time. I still don't see any case in which this doesn't find the optimal solution.

Comment: Suppose you need to pick up people in the following cities and this is the optimal route too: Madrid, Rome, Vienna, Prague, Berlin, Zurich, Amsterdam, Brussels, London. Now if you add Milan to that problem, your algorithm will get Madrid, Milan, Rome, Vienna, Prague, Berlin, Zurich, Amsterdam, Brussels, London. But the new optimal solution is Madrid, Milan, Zurich, Rome, Vienna, Prague, Berlin, Amsterdam, Brussels, London. Notice how adding Milan made Zurich move from the top line to the bottom line.

Comment: Well, this is again because the route doesn't go mainly in one direction, which I excluded from my problem set above. A typical use case should look like this: https://db.tt/oHg2tiqv

Comment: Interesting. If A is your starting point, by what formal definition are 2 points B and C "mainly in the same direction"? Iff A, B and C are connectible through a straight line, then yes it's optimal. Otherwise, presuming that C is close to the A-B line, I'd guess it *might* be near optimal (if the no pickups go in the opposite direction of course).

Comment: Anyway, my guess is, even taken these constraints into account, your algorithm is not likely to be optimal in all cases, but it's probably "good enough" in all cases.

Comment: Currently I try to build a good enough implement and if it proves to be of interest to others I'll improve and re-implement that part with a more sophisticated solution. Currently I check if the time for each individual passenger is not more then 150% of the optimal path. If the quality drops too much, the new passenger is rejected.